# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"naver:openapi", local:"geocode"). Expected elements are <{}geocode>

Tags: java, xml

I'm use Naver coperation Map OpenAPI.

API is return XML value. so, i parsing xml but error occur.

please check this code.

**response xml code**

```
<geocode xmlns="naver:openapi">
    <userquery>
        <![CDATA[ 서울중구태평로2가23 ]]>
    </userquery>
    <total>4</total>
    <item>
        <point>
            <x>126.9779131</x>
            <y>37.5646854</y>
        </point>
        <address>서울특별시 중구 태평로2가 23</address>
        <addrdetail>
            <sido>
                        <![CDATA[ 서울특별시 ]]>
                <sigugun>
                                <![CDATA[ 중구 ]]>
                    <dongmyun>
                                        <![CDATA[ 태평로2가 ]]>
                        <rest>
                                                <![CDATA[ 23 ]]>
                        </rest>
                    </dongmyun>
                </sigugun>
            </sido>
        </addrdetail>
    </item>
</geocode>
```

I parsing this xml code (HttpURLConnection)

`is = con.getInputStream();
JAXBContext jaxbCtx = JAXBContext.newInstance(User.class);
User user = (User) jaxbCtx.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(is);`

User Instance is

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "geocode")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class User {

    private String geocode;
    private List<Item> item;
    private int errorCode;
    private int total;
    private String userquery;
        ......
```

and Error is occur

Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"naver:openapi", local:"geocode"). Expected elements are <{}geocode>

what is problem??